# Landscape only iPad application using Mono Touch

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm using Mono Touch to develop a landscape-only iPad application but the simulator doesn't seem to rotate any of the views (or the main window for that matter) to landscape.

I've set the **SDK** version and **Minimum OS** version to `4.2`.
I have also set the Supported Orientations to `Landscape`.

Furthermore, I've created a Navigation Controller which overrides the `ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and sets it to return true. I then added it using `window.AddSubview(navigationController.View)` but that didn't help either.

I'm using the Rotate Left/Right methods (under Hardware) in the simulator but the whole app rotates with the window and the app stays in `Portrait` mode. Even the status bar (carrier, time, battery) go off to the right instead of moving up to the top of the screen.

**Help?! Anyone?!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the `UIInterfaceOrientation` key to landscape as well?

Also, in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` you'll want to only return true if the new orientation matches the orientation you want.

Comment: I'm returning true because at the moment I can't get it to rotate to ANY orientation. And yes I have set the `UIInterfaceOrientation` to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` in the Info.plist file.

Comment: But does it actually get called? The OS sometimes uses that message as a way to test which orientations are valid even absent a rotation event - if it is getting called it should only return true on landscape, and otherwise the system may be sending it to another view controller instead.

Comment: Also, you're sure that the orientation lock isn't on in the simulator, right?